# Ubuntu/Linux - Cannot see files in folders when connected to a DFS tree on Windows Server

Tags: linux

Using Ubuntu (Linux Mint 12) I have been able to connect to a DFS shared tree on our Windows file server/domain using this command from a terminal window:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -v //fs4/jmcroot ~/fs4 -o username=myname,password=mypassword
```

"jmcroot" is the DFS root name on our Windows 2003 file server, named "fs4".
~/fs4 is my local folder where I want to host the mounted DFS tree.

Once mounted (and still working from the terminal window) I can use the CD and LS commands to see and read every folder and file in the mounted folder. It all works, *from the terminal window*.

HOWEVER, when I go to the Linux desktop and use the Nautilus file browser, when I click on the mounted path (fs4), I can see folder names, but then when I click on a folder, expecting to see the files in that folder, it gives a message box "The folder contents could not be displayed. Sorry, could not display all the contents ofr "": Not a directoey."

Again, I *CAN* see these files using the CD and LS commands from a terminal window, but not from the Nautilus file browser, which is where I need to work from.

[image: Terminal Window]

[image: Nautilus]

[image: Message Box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this!!!  After hours and hours of Googling and trial-and-error.

Here is the solution, thoroughly detailed in a blog post I wrote:

http://mattslay.com/connecting-ubuntu-to-windows-shares-and-dfs-trees/

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before from the command line.  It's usually a DNS problem.  Check your KeyUtil files, make sure that the setup matches what I listed on [my blog post](http://pinchii.com/home/2011/02/mounting-dfs-to-redhat-linux-enterprise-5-centos-5/)

as you can see the Screenshot bellow {screen shot blocked}, I can browse from Konqueror (which should be similar to Nautilus)

The only other thing i can think is that Nautilus doesn't really obey the Keytools DNS lookup settigns for CIFS connections

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I CAN ping the server by it's name (FS4) and IP address. But, Nautilus still cannot see files in the folders. Also, I am on Ubuntu. You're success was on Redhat / CentOS. I am exhausted from this. Maybe I could work with you to remote in and help out? You available to consult me through this?