# DFS and Access Based Enumeration - Unix devices cannot access it

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, unix, ubuntu-13.04

I'm currently experiencing issues with DFS shares and ABE, enabled on a Windows Server 2008 R2 File Server. Everything works fine with Windows, the problem is with Linux/Unix machines.

They aren't able (with the same username) to access the namespace at all:
\fileserver\namespace\folder1\subfolder1

I can't access it at all. All I can do is mounting \fileserver\ and see all the available shares:
admin$; c$; d$; f$; Namespace

Also from here, I can't access them. Since I manage the Windows Servers and not the unix boxes, I've installed a VM to test it myself, and indeed it doesn't work (Ubuntu 13.04). Even when I use the GUI, it won't work, I'm only able to see the above shares but not access them.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems to be what you're looking for :

Matt Shay originally posted an identical questions regarding mounting dfs shares in linux ([Ubuntu/Linux - Cannot see files in folders when connected to a DFS tree on Windows Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/370338/ubuntu-linux-cannot-see-files-in-folders-when-connected-to-a-dfs-tree-on-windo))

He solved his own question and put this guide up on connecting to a dfs within Linux.

> I never solved the problem, that is, until I tried again in October 2012. I’m now running Ubuntu 12.04. So, I started all over… I tried a bunch of things from Google… And I finally got it working, even from “Connect to Server” in Nautilus!!!

http://mattslay.com/connecting-ubuntu-to-windows-shares-and-dfs-trees/

Comment: Link only answers are not helpful if the link breaks.  Can you add detail from the link to improve this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've been in contact with Unix team in my company and they went back to HP which closed the discussion saying: DFS is not supported with Win Server 2008 R2. Ergo, I got to create a new share outside of the DFS share and everybody was happy again.. Also, Unix didn't even like the Virtual IP assigned to that VM!

Answer (score 2):

DFS Referrals for domain-integrated namespaces happen via Active Directory and leverage Active Directory Sites and Services topology information to function. DFS Namespaces do not function on Windows computers that aren't joined to the domain, nevermind Linux computers. There *may* be something in the Samba package to deal with this, but I doubt it. You may be out of luck here.